# Recover missing dll files

Tags: windows-10, restore, dll

I am currently using MAlwarebytes free version and am getting fed up with the constant pop ups asking me to purchase the premium version.
As a result, I made the massive mistake of trying Zemana as after researching I was lead to believe that it was just as good...

I ran a scan and all it seemed to find were files related to McAfee, AMD Radeon and WPS Office.

I Marked all these files as safe.

However, now I get constant error messages. I cannot open WPS office because there are missing dll files,

Namely:
ksolite.dll
QtNetwork4.dll
kdownload.dll
krpt.dll

I cannot reinstall or uninstall to then reinstall because these .dll files appear to be used for install/uninstall of this program

Also Radeon does not run because there are missing .dll files - 
libEGL.dll
Qt5Quick.dll
Qt5WebEngine.dll
Qt5Widgets.dll

I managed to uninstall and reinstall McAfee which seems to have solved the issues I had with that but WPS OFfice and Radeon, no such luck

Also, These are the issues I have found, I dare say that there may be other issues with other programs which I am yet to find.

I was hoping someone could advise as to how to find any issues that there may be?

And also how to resolve these .dll issues?

Thanks in advance

---

I have searched online and found where these files should be stored and checked the relevant folders.

It appears that these drivers are in the folders that they should be in but for some reason, not being registered when loading the programs.

Is there something I can do to resolve this issue?

Comment: That is why, I just use windows defender :|

Comment: You need to reinstall the products that are broken. You cannot find random DLLs to replace those deleted and simply copy them into place.

Comment: @music2myear I tried that but was unable to uninstall or reinstall some of the programs due to the missing drivers, so left me in a difficult position

Answer (score 1):

How many antivirus apps have you had on there at any one time?
If the answer is "more than one" that was the start of your problem.

McAfee gets given away 'free' with computers because that's the only way they can get any customers. Malwarebytes isn't as good as they'd like you to think & who the heck is Zemana?

The worst antivirus apps will quarantine things without bothering to tell you. Having multiple antivirus apps at any given time means they will fight over who is in charge, one flagging the actions of the other as malware. This is not a situation to get yourself into.
This happens with ones like McAffe, which people get the free trial of when they buy their computer, then when it runs out they just leave it there, assuming it has magically become inactive. It hasn't & it will continue to mess things up without ever telling you, until you actually uninstall it.
You can have one active & one passive, like Malwarebytes free version - not the paid & not the trial of the paid version, they're active.
Defender is told to no longer be the active antivirus if another active is installed, so doesn't count towards this.

As there is no absolute authority on antivirus apps, you have to trust something like [AV-TEST](https://www.av-test.org/en/antivirus/home-windows/), who at least make the antivirus makers pay to have their software tested, which at least keeps the complete chancers out of the list. If you look through their data historically you will also note that occasionally some of the better-known ones drop down the list, then sometimes vanish for a while, as they struggle to get their act together again.

General rule, pick something from the top half of their list, when sorted by 'protection' but paying attention to 'performance' [which is how much it slows your computer down.]
Don't pick anything from the bottom half, for obvious reasons & don't pick anything that not on the list at all - because even if this is not the absolute authority on who is best, it is at least a recognised authority, as far as that goes in this industry.

In the meantime, once you have uninstalled **all** your antiviruses, then you may have a chance to run repair installs of the bits they fought over &/or quarantined without asking you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was running 2 AV - McAfee and the free version of Malwarebytes. I then opted for Zemana based on reviews (I was advised that McAfee and Malwarebytes were better for detecting different types of threats)

Comment: I need to restore the missing .dll files as they are impacting programs which are pivotal to running my business. are there any proven ways to restore these files?

Comment: The free Malware Bytes product is not Anti-virus software in the same way McAfee is.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure how to resolve the issue

What I did do though was a system restore and luckily I had a restore point from 24 hours ago which minimised the damage